# react-router-dom renders only first route

Tags: reactjs

I just started learning react and ran into a problem when I tried to use react-router-dom I ran into a problem that only the first component is rendered for all routes defined

Here is HomePage.js that defines the routes

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Categories from "./categories";
import Category from "./category";
import ListingItem from "./listing_item";
import { 
BrowserRouter as Router, 
Switch, 
Route, 
Redirect, 
Link 
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class HomePage extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="" component={ListingItem}/>
      <Route path="categories/" component={Categories}/>
      <Route path="category/" component={Category}/>
      </Switch>
  </Router>
);
}}
```

I tried the "category" and "categories" components with the exact path and without the exact and still only the first component is rendered

Here are the components:
listing_item component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ListingItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <p>This is the Item Listing page</p>
    }
}
```

category

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Category extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <p>This is a single Category page</p>
    }
}
```

and categories is the same structure

Here is App.js that renders Homepage

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";


export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <HomePage />
            </div>
            );
    }
}
const AppDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, AppDiv)
```

Comment: Put `path="/"` from your home page and put `path="/categories"` `/` must be in beginning of your `route` name.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without changing the URLs because this is a Django app and I need to keep the URLs like that as when I change them I get into another error where nothing is rendered at all, not even the first component

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax issue that might cause the problem.

```
export default class category extends Component
```

should be

```
export default class Category extends Component{
```

and

```
export default class listing_item extends Component
```

should be

```
export default class ListingItem extends Component
```

Comment: can you explain why?
I have the classes defined with these names "category" all lower an "listing_item"

Comment: In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. However, lower-case tag names with a dot (property accessor) aren't.

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

<component /> compiles to React.createElement('component') (html tag)
<Component /> compiles to React.createElement(Component)
<obj.component /> compiles to React.createElement(obj.component)

Comment: I updated my code and the question to match the class names to be in pascal case, yet the problem is not solved and it started to drive me crazy